# Inserting records into Mongodb using Pymongo is using up my RAM incrementally and is eventually exhausting all memory

Tags: mongodb, python

I am writing Python code that parses through a huge XML document of size 17GB(Wikipedia collection) and inserts each page title along with the links in that page (storing as a list) present on the page in a MongoDB collection. I am inserting using the command `links.insert_one(data)` where`data` is a dictionary consisting of the following

```
data = {
          'document': self.title, # a string (basically title of the Wikipedia page)
          'links': self.links # list of strings (all hyperlinked words in a page)
       }

<db_name>.insert_one(data)
```

I am repeating this process for every page (around 19 million pages)

When I monitor my RAM usage(using htop in Ubuntu), I see that the amount of RAM used by MongoDB keeps increasing and continues till all my memory is used eventually crashing the system.

I have also made the following observation when I comment out the insertion statement and execute the code, it works fine. So, I presume that the problem is with my MongoDB insertion process and not with the actual python logic.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the WiredTiger cache size, see [hardware considerations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#prod-notes-ram).

Other than this, run MongoDB on containers (Kubernetes, Docker, rkt), where you can easily control resource usage. If you are using *systemd* for running MongoDB, you can also set [resource usage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Reducing the default memory which WiredTiger uses to a custom limit worked for me.